# How to pass extra parameter in listview incase of itemView as a function in yii2

Tags: php, listview, yii2, listviewitem, yii2-advanced-app

how to pass extra parameter in listview. incase the itemview as function

```
<?
echo ListView::widget( [
'dataProvider' => $dataProviderbooking,
'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
return $this->render('_itembookingview',['model' => $model,'index'=>$index]);
// or just do some echo
// return $model->title . ' posted by ' . $model->author;
},
'viewParams'=>['dataType'=>$dataType],
] ); ?>
```

the viewparams is get only the itemview is string type.how to fix this.

Answer (score 0):

From docs to [$viewParams](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$viewParams-detail).

> Additional parameters to be passed to `$itemView` when it is being
>   rendered. This property is used only when `$itemView` is a string
>   representing a view name.

So you need to pass it along with other params in callback:

```
'itemView' => function ($model, $key, $index, $widget) {
    return $this->render('_itembookingview', [
        'model' => $model,
        'index' => $index,
        'dataType' => $dataType,
        // Pass as many params as you want here
   ]);
},
```

But from your code I don't get any benefit of using this. You can use string representing the view name in `itemView` and pass other params in `viewParams`, because `$model` and `$index` are passed by default. See docs to [$itemView](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-listview.html#$itemView-detail).

Comment: Is there a reason, why you don't use the parameters `$key` and `$widget` in that anonymous functions? Is it not needed?